# How can I avoid stackoverflow exception

Tags: java, recursion, arraylist, java-8, stack-overflow

I have a list of hierarchical objects and I have to remove a hierarchy if a hierarchy has a value as zero.

I have to remove all the managers(employees) 
if and only if emp salary is 0 and there are no employees under him. 
OR all the employees under him having zero salary.
But not if manager salary is having zero and employees under him does not have zero salary.

Eg.

```
emp(10)
    |---- empA(9)
            |---- empAa(8)
            |---- empAb(7)
            |---- empAc(0)
    |---- empB(7)
            |---- empBa(0)
                    |---- empBaa(0)
                            |---- empBaaa(0)
            |---- empBb(0)
                    |---- empBba(4)
```

above structure has to be modified as below.

```
emp(10)
    |---- empA(9)
            |---- empAa(8)
            |---- empAb(7)
    |---- empB(7)
            |---- empBb(0)
                    |---- empBba(4)
```

I am getting stackoverflow exception when the input list is big. how should I enhance this logic to avoid SOFE.

```
    removeHierarchy(List<Employee> managers){
        int count = 0;
        if(null != managers && !managers.isEmpty()){
            for(Employee manager: managers){
            List<Employee> toBeRemoved = new ArrayList<>();
            List<Employee> employees = manager.getEmployees();
                if(0 == manager.getSalary()){
                    if(null == employees || employees.isEmpty()){
                        toBeRemoved.add(manager);
                    } else {
                        ++count;
                        removeHierarchy(employees);
                    }
                } else {
                    removeHierarchy(employees);
                }
                managers.removeAll(toBeRemoved);
            }
        }

        for(int i=0; i < count; i++){
            removeHierarchy(managers);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please post the stack trace. I think a Graph / Tree would better suit your needs!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think your problem is that you don't actually remove any employees from the lists. If the list has such configuration - you will go in infinite cycles on last lines.

```
emp(0)
 |---- empA(0)
```

It seems the last lines should be something like `managers.removeAll(toBeRemoved)`

Here is working function:

```
void removeHierarchy( List<Employee> managers )
  {
    List<Employee> toBeRemoved = new ArrayList<>();
    for ( Employee manager : managers )
    {
      removeHierarchy( manager.getEmployees() );
      if (0 == manager.getSalary() && manager.getEmployees().isEmpty()) {
        toBeRemoved.add( manager );
      }
    }
    managers.removeAll( toBeRemoved );
  }
```

See [full test code](https://gist.github.com/ddobrotvorskiy/05a8986f9844ad90084e540067526704)

Comment: I have updated my question. I have managers.removeAll( toBeRemoved ); in my code but still giving SOFE when the list is with around 17 managers with three levels in each.

Comment: @Extreme but you’re not always removing all sub nodes, i.e. consider that `|---- empBb(0) |---- empBba(4)` branch. So the list will not be empty in that case, but for some reason you’re calling `removeHierarchy(managers);` again with exactly the same list in that loop at the method’s end. Having the same input, it will do exactly the same, including calling itself again with the same input ending up in an infinite loop.

Answer (score 0):

I think this program has multiple problems.

1. You cannot iterate over a list and try to manipulate it at same time
2. There's is no logic to remove the identified managers/employees

As suggested by John, I'm adding method that can perform the required task. It is no different that the solution provided in other answer except that I have used Java 8 syntactic sugar.

```
public static boolean removeEmployee(Employee employee)
{
    employee.setEmployees(employee.getEmployees().stream().filter(Employee::removeEmployee).collect(Collectors.toList()));
    return !(employee.getSalary()==0 && employee.getEmployees().size()==0);
}
```

Note: Make sure your array list (list of employees) is not null i.e., empty array list when you create an employee object.

Comment: Your points are correct, but I think this "answer" could be turned into an actual answer by editing it to answer the question, "how should I enhance this logic to avoid SOFE?" (i.e. You can enhance the logic by 1. Adding code to remove the identified managers/employees. 2. Don't use a for-each loop which uses iterators, instead use a regular for loop and remove from the list correctly.) Something along those lines.

Answer (score 0):

To decide whether you have to keep or remove an `Employee`, you must first process her employees' list:

```
void removeHierarchy(List<Employee> managers){
    if(null != managers && !managers.isEmpty()){
        List<Employee> toBeRemoved = new ArrayList<>();
        for(Employee manager: managers) {
            List<Employee> employees = manager.getEmployees();
            removeHierarchy(employees);
            if (0 == manager.getSalary()
                    && (null == employees || employees.isEmpty())) {
                toBeRemoved.add(manager);
            }
        }
        managers.removeAll(toBeRemoved);
    }
}
```